# Using a vector of integers in the `from` argument of seq

Tags: r, vector, integer, sequence

Is there any function that can generate a vector of numbers using multiple values in `seq(from = )`?

For example, I would like to generate a vector of numbers from `1:3` to `50` with an increment of `7`. The output should be

```
sort(c(seq(1, 50, 7), seq(2, 50, 7), seq(3, 50, 7)))
[1]  1  2  3  8  9 10 15 16 17 22 23 24 29 30 31 36 37 38 43 44 45 50
```

Currently I'm using a `sapply` to wrap around `1:3`, which I think is not very elegant.

```
sort(unlist(sapply(1:3, \(x) seq(x, 50, 7))))
```

Comment: Look at `?sequence`.

Comment: Maybe `sort(unlist(sapply(1:3, seq, to = 50, by = 7)))` ?

Comment: Your `sapply` solution seems just fine. `sapply` will default to using the first argument so you can simplify the syntax slightly to `sort(unlist(lapply(1:3, seq, to = 50, by = 7))))`. Or you could do something like `outer(seq(1, 50, 7), 0:2, "+")`

Comment: (I'd also recommend `lapply` not `sapply` since `sapply` isn't able to do any simplification here... which will depend on whether or not the subsequences are the same length. `lapply` is type stable and therefore predictable.)

Comment: @NicChr: `sequence()` is a hidden gem but a little awkward in this case because it doesn't have a `to` argument (only `nvec` (length), `from`, and `by`)

Comment: @Ben Bolker, please look at my answer. It is very easy to utilise a `from` and `to` argument.

Comment: Fair enough: I just meant that the `(to-from)/by` part had to be implemented (and I was feeling lazy). It's a useful alternative, although I'm not sure it's significantly better or worse than the simplified `lapply()` syntax suggested by @AllanCameron and @GregorThomas (it would take a pretty huge scale to see a noticeable performance difference)

Comment: @NicChr Yes I'm aware of the `sequence` function, I also tried a bit myself but cannot figure out the correct syntax to generate my desired output. Your answer is useful!

Comment: @Ben Bolker My answer is implemented in one line of code, how lazy of an answer were you expecting? :)

Comment: Just to add, tou could also use `Vectorize()`: `sort(unlist(Vectorize(seq.default, vectorize.args = c("to", "from"))(1:3, 50, 7)))`

Comment: If you want a really concise answer then `sort(seq(1,155,7)%%55)[1:22]`  or ```outer(1:3,0:7*7,`+`)[1:22]``` give the correct output and are pretty short albeit not generalizable

Comment: @Ben Bolker running `seqv(from = seq_len(10^5), to = 10^5, by = 100)` runs in 50ms and requires ~ 200MB, whereas `unlist(lapply(seq_len(10^5), function(x) seq(from = x, to = 10^5, by = 100)))` runs in 7 seconds and requires 1.4GB of memory. I'd argue it scales horribly for this kind of problem.

Comment: I didn't say the `lapply()` answer scaled well: I said that it would require a large-scale problem (which your example is) to see a difference. On the OP's problem, `lapply()` takes a median of 90 microseconds, `seqv` takes 30 microsecs ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a vectorised version using `sequence()`.

No loops required. :)

```r
seqv <- function(from, to, by = 1){
  sequence( ((to - from) / by) + 1, from = from, by = by)
}

sort(seqv(1:3, 50, 7))
[1]  1  2  3  8  9 10 15 16 17 22 23 24 29 30 31 36 37 38 43 44 45 50
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
> sort(unlist(Map(seq, from = 1:3, to = 50, by = 7)))
 [1]  1  2  3  8  9 10 15 16 17 22 23 24 29 30 31 36 37 38 43 44 45 50
```